# Designing a specific grid movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, 2d-games

what I'm trying to achieve, is that **while** the player holds the mouse button

on a tile (any grid element, verically or horizontally aligned with the player), the player will move towards that tile with the possible directions of left,right,up,down only.

currently my code doesn't work for while pressing the mouse button, I think it has something to do with the raycasting.

second thing I want to achieve is that while the player is moving in the grid, if the player decides to change direction, he will be able, no matter if it's just opposite direction, or if he decideds to take a sudden turn left/right.

(I managed to achieve it without using the isMoving boolean condition only in the opposite direction, but I added it because when the player clicked while moving it slowed him down)

right now no change in movement while moving is available.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Holoville.HOTween;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 100f;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;
    private float startTime;
    private float journeyLength;
    private tile currentTile;
    private tile tileToMove;
    private float angleToTurn = 0f;
    private bool isMoving = false;
    public static Player use;

    void Awake()
    {
        use = this;
    }

    void Start () {

        startPos = endPos = transform.position;
        tileToMove = currentTile = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[0];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        MovePlayer();

        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;

        if (!startPos.Equals(endPos))
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, fracJourney);

        if (transform.position == endPos)
        {
            isMoving = false;
        }
    }

    void MovePlayer()
    {
        Ray ray;
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !isMoving)
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldGenerator.use.tilesList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.collider.Raycast(ray, out hit, float.PositiveInfinity))
                {
                    if (fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.x < transform.position.x && fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.y == transform.position.y)
                    {
                        angleToTurn = -180f;
                        tileToMove = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i];
                        isMoving = true;
                    }
                    else if (fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.x > transform.position.x && fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.y == transform.position.y)
                    {
                        angleToTurn = 0;
                        tileToMove = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i];
                        isMoving = true;
                    }
                    else if (fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.y < transform.position.y && fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.x == transform.position.x)
                    {
                        angleToTurn = -90f;
                        tileToMove = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i];
                        isMoving = true;
                    }
                    else if (fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.y > transform.position.y && fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.x == transform.position.x)
                    {
                        angleToTurn = 90f;
                        tileToMove = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i];
                        isMoving = true;
                    }

                    startTime = Time.time;
                    startPos = transform.position;
                    endPos = tileToMove.selfObject.transform.position;
                    journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startPos, endPos);
                    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, angleToTurn);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure on what you're doing with the tiles and raycasting but here's how i'd do it. Apologies for the formatting, it's just how I work.

EDIT: Okay, given you said 'grid' movement I assumed the tiles were equidistant from each other. GetMouseButtonDown changed to GetMouseButton as well. This will mean that a ray is shot every update which you may want to look into making more efficient.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Holoville.HOTween;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed          = 100.0f;
    private float delta         = 0.0f;
    private float distance      = 1.0f;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;
    private tile currentTile;
    private tile tileToMove;
    private float angleToTurn   = 0f;
    private bool isMoving       = false;
    public static Player use;

    void Awake() {
        use = this;
    }

    void Start () {
        startPos = endPos = transform.position;
        tileToMove = currentTile = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[0];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        GetInput();
        MovePlayer();
    }

    void MovePlayer() {
        if ( isMoving ) {
            if ( delta < 1 ) {
                // Distance independant movement.
                delta += ( speed/distance ) * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, delta);
            } else {
                isMoving = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void GetInput() {
        Ray ray;
        RaycastHit hit;

        if ( Input.GetMouseButton(0) ) {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldGenerator.use.tilesList.Count; i++) {
                if ( fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.collider.Raycast( ray, out hit, float.PositiveInfinity ) ) {
                    if (fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.x < transform.position.x && fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.y == transform.position.y) {
                        angleToTurn = -180f;
                        tileToMove = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i];
                        isMoving = true;
                    } else if (fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.x > transform.position.x && fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.y == transform.position.y) {
                        angleToTurn = 0;
                        tileToMove = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i];
                        isMoving = true;
                    } else if (fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.y < transform.position.y && fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.x == transform.position.x) {
                        angleToTurn = -90f;
                        tileToMove = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i];
                        isMoving = true;
                    } else if (fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.y > transform.position.y && fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i].selfObject.transform.position.x == transform.position.x) {
                        angleToTurn = 90f;
                        tileToMove = fieldGenerator.use.tilesList[i];
                        isMoving = true;
                    }

                    isMoving    = true;
                    delta           = 0f;
                    startPos        = transform.position;
                    endPos      = tileToMove.selfObject.transform.position;
                    distance        = Vector3.Distance( startPos, endPos );
                    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, angleToTurn);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work while the mouse is pressed, also the speed is increasing if you move to further tiles, and decreasing if you move to near tiles

Comment: Editted. Untested but it should work. You might want to look at doing a raycast every few frames for efficiency. Raycasting on Update is heavy processing.